# Add class on div on a button click

Tags: angular

I have a div on which i want to add a transition on delete, I have a button to delete it. what is the way to add the css class to that div on triggering a button.

The div are created in *ngFor loop.

```
<div *ngFor="let attribute of attributes>
    <div [ngClass]="{' roll-out-blurred-left': a  }">
            {{attribute.name}} // on that div wants to add the class 
    </div> 
     <button (click)="onDelete(attribute)>
</div>
```

Comment: you can assign with `[ngClass]` another class. Add a custom attributes to the definition of the `attributes` setted to false by default. Then `onDelete` pass the `id` releated to the attribute, and se the field you have just created to `!` (IE: attribute.showAnimation = !attribute.showAnimation`). then in the ngClass -> [attribute.showAnimation ? 'yourClassForAnimation' : 'yourClassForNoAnimation']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the following approach. I am considering you have some ID to each attribute over which you are looping and adding divs. Like this:

```
attributes = [
    {"id": 0, "name": "one"},
    {"id": 1, "name": "two"},
    {"id": 2, "name": "three"}
];
```

Maintain a variable which indicates the current ID of an attribute (div) which is clicked. now in '*ngFor'. Let's say this is stored in the variable named 'removeId'. Add a class to the div if 'removeId' is equal to the ID of the attribute(div).

```
[ngClass]="{'idToRemove': attr.id == removeId}"
```

Now on click of the button, set value of 'removeId' to respective div ID. Let's say button click calls a function called 'removeDiv' and accepts respective div id as parameter. Like this:

```
<div class="Nodelete" [ngClass]="{'idToRemove': attr.id == removeId}"> 
   {{attr.name}}
   <button (click)="removeDiv(attr.id)">Delete</button>
</div>
```

And in function removeDiv, do this:

```
removeDiv(index) {
 this.removeId = index;
}
```

You can see the working example [here.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-un3cu4?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

I am just changing the background color of the clicked div for simplicity.

Comment: your code works, but i can't apply transitions on delete because on deleting it actually removes from the DOM at same time.

Answer (score 1):

As a simple approach, I would prefer setting an extra flag key (let's say `isDeleted`, if it doesn't hurt) to each attribute object.
This keeps track of the state that whether the specific class (let's say we want to apply `deleted` class to the `div` on corresponding button click) is currently active (applied) or not.

**component.html**

```
<div *ngFor="let attribute of attributes; let i = index">
    <div [ngClass]="{ 'deleted': attribute.isDeleted  }">
      {{ attribute.name }}
    </div> 
    <button (click)="onDelete(i)">Toggle</button>
</div>
```

*By passing index of the button we can set `isDeleted` key to `true` or `false` on the corresponding attribute object.*

**component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  attributes = [
    { name: 'first' },
    { name: 'second' },
    { name: 'third' },
    { name: 'fourth' },
    { name: 'fifth' },
    { name: 'sixth' },
    { name: 'seventh' },
  ];

  onDelete(index: number) {
      // Toggle class on corresponding div
      this.attributes[index]['isDeleted'] = !this.attributes[index]['isDeleted'];
  }
}
```

**component.scss**

```
.deleted {
  // Your styles here
  color: red;
}
```

Test [here](https://angular-yirjwk.stackblitz.io).

Comment: your code works, but i can't apply transitions on delete because on deleting it actually removes from the DOM at same time.

Answer (score 0):

Angular provide some way to add class with the condition

there are different type :

**type one**

```
[class.my-class]="condition=='condition1'"
```

**type two**

```
[ngClass]="{'my-class': condition=='condition1'}"
```

**type three**

```
[ngClass]="{1:'my-class1',2:'my-class2',3:'my-class4'}[condition]"
```

**type four**

```
[ngClass]="(condition=='condition1')?'my-class1':'my-class2'"
```

So in your cases use attribute as condition and choose a type according to your need.